# SharePoint 2019 custom form based authentication using active directory "site not shared with you"

Tags: c#, iis, sharepoint, active-directory, ldap

The achievement which I would like to achieve is that I would like to create a custom login page (FBA) to authenticate users from active directory. The user got two domains with trusted domain forest so users from both AD can login. Currently I'm using the below approach:

I created a custom page to login SharePoint 2019, the code in login page uses below lines to authenticate the user:

```
        SecurityToken token = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication
                                         (new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url),
                                         "admembers",
                                         "",
                                         _userName,
                                         _password,
                                         (SPFormsAuthenticationOption) 0);
        SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(token);
```

The above lines comes from the link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42541/how-to-create-a-custom-fba-login-page-that-forces-user-to-change-password-and-vi

I followed this guide http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com/2013/05/setting-up-forms-based-authentication.html (This site was for SharePoint 2010 but I can't find much for SharePoint 2019) to set up the FBA

Mainly I changed 3 web.configs:

1. The site application web.config
2. The central administration web.config
3. The Security Token Service web.config

**Security Token Service:**

For the security token service web.config I added below code to the end:

```
      <connectionStrings>
            <add name="adconn"
                   connectionString="LDAP://Sharepoint2019.int/DC=Sharepoint2019,DC=int" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
            <membership defaultProvider="admembers">
                  <providers>
                        <add name="admembers"
                               type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                               connectionStringName="adconn"
                               enableSearchMethods="true"
                               attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
                  </providers>
            </membership>
      </system.web>
```

**Central administration:**

For the central administration web.config I added below code after the "`</SharePoint>`" tag:

```
      <connectionStrings>
            <add name="adconn"
                   connectionString="LDAP://Sharepoint2019.int/DC=Sharepoint2019,DC=int" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

I've also added the below code to the "PeoplePickerWildCards" node

```
<add key="admembers" value="%" />
```

Moreover, I modified the default membership tag to below

```
            <membership defaultProvider="admembers">
                  <providers>
                        <add name="admembers"
                               type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                               connectionStringName="adconn"
                               enableSearchMethods="true"
                               attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
                  </providers>
            </membership>
```

**Site application:**

For the site application, I added the below code

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="adconn" connectionString="LDAP://Sharepoint2019.int/DC=Sharepoint2019,DC=int" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Also, I've added the below code to the "PeoplePickerWildcard"

```
<add key="admembers" value="%" />
```

Moreover, I added the below code to the membership provider:

```
                        <add name="admembers"
                               type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                               connectionStringName="adconn"
                               enableSearchMethods="true"
                               attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
```

Then in the central administration, I selected the web application, enabled form authentication, set the default membership provider name to "admembers" and point the custom login page to "_layout\LoginPage\login.aspx"

**Result:**

The result was that I was able to use the farm admin account (Which is a site owner) to login the website. However, an error message "site hasn't been shared with you" appeared.

I've tested the LDAP path by below code:
var ldapPath = "DC=corp,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com";

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://Sharepoint2019.int/DC=Sharepoint2019,DC=int"))  {
    using(var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry)) {
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=spAdministrator*))";
        SearchResultCollection result = searcher.FindAll();
        
    }
}
```

The result was able to find that user

Does anyone have any advice which I did wrong or am I using the correct approach?

Comment: See : https://vigneshsharepointthoughts.com/2017/02/21/resolving-sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you-sharepoint-site-error/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed from Microsoft that the default form based authentication does not work in this way, the default form based authentication only works with the user set in the user policy.

There is no way to use the default form based authentication and windows authentication with multiple zones. Multiple authentication methods result in multiple SharePoint user profile which is not what we want.

At last, the Azure active directory was integrated to fulfill the form-based authentication requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to go to Site Permissions of the site in which this Logon page is hosted, and use Check Permissions to see if the user you are trying to log on with has Permissions to see the Site.

Comment: I'm using farm admin accounts which already have the right and I can log in via windows authentication